# Многопоточность в Python - multiprocessing Pool

Tags: python, многопоточность, selenium, selenium-webdriver, multiprocessing

Дан код:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time
from selenium import webdriver
import csv


urls_list = ["https://stackoverflow.com", "https://instagram.com", "https://vk.com"]

with open("tren.csv", "w") as f:
    pass

def get_data(url):
    try:
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\..\chromedriver.exe")
        driver.get(url=url)
        time.sleep(5)

        LIST = []
        LIST.append(url)
        LIST.append([url])  #???
        with open("tren.csv", "a") as w1:
            w = csv.writer(w1, delimiter = ";", lineterminator = '\n')
            w.writerow(LIST)
      
        
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
    finally:
        driver.close()
        driver.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(processes=3)
    p.map(get_data, urls_list)
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно добавить в tren.csv все урлы + их индекс, то есть должно получиться в итоге:

```
https://stackoverflow.com; 0
https://instagram.com; 1
https://vk.com; 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы не рекомендовал писать в один файл из разных потоков. Лучше возвращайте из `get_data` всё, что нужно через `return`, и собирайте результаты, итерируясь по `p.map(...` да пишите их в файл. Что-то типа такого:

```
with open("tren.csv", "a") as w1:
    w = csv.writer(w1, delimiter = ";", lineterminator = '\n')
    for res in p.map(get_data, urls_list):
        w.writerow(res)
```

Для нумерации лучше сделать `enumerate`, но где именно его сделать - зависит от того, хотите вы, чтобы нумерация была от исходного списка или от порядка, в котором потоки успели отработать.

```
p.map(get_data, enumerate(urls_list))
```

или

```
enumerate(p.map(get_data, urls_list))
```

Comment: То есть так должен выглядеть if name; 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(processes=3

with open("tren.csv", "a") as w1:
    w = csv.writer(w1, delimiter = ";", lineterminator = '\n')
    for res in p.map(get_data, urls_list):
        w.writerow(res)
+ enumerate?

Comment: @ChikChirik Ну да, как-то так. Вы определитесь, что именно хотите нумеровать. Осталось только нумерацию приделать, если с этим затруднение будет, я напишу полностью код, но вроде это не сложно. Да, и `pool` кажется тоже лучше с `with` открывать, как и `file`.

Comment: нумерация по сути не важна и та и та вроде подходит, суть в том что у меня для каждого урла будет на основе сбора данных создаваться несколько списков, которые потом будут записываться в файл. А потому нужно было для каждого списка, относящегося к одному урлу прописать одинаковый идентификатор, то есть индекс урла.

Comment: Вроде как все получилось, но похоже мой пк не тянет даже 2 потока, окна закрываются у некоторых урлов, всегда по разному, якобы ничего не найдено, хотя если делать 1 поток, то все работает как надо, не знаете может дело не в пк?

Comment: @ChikChirik Сложный вопрос. Смотря что за сайты и т.д. Может эти сайты не дают в два потока с одного ip обращаться, если это ссылки на одном сайте. Нужно копать, разбираться. И лучше смотрите в сторону `asyncio`, если хотите многопоточный ввод-вывод. Мультипроцессинг - это для расчётов и т.д. А где упирается во ввод-вывод, там async/await надо использовать.

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое за помощь, попробую разобраться с asyncio, инфы по по ней, конечно меньше, чем по мультипроцессингу..